# Stream sorted() method doesn't reflect the sorted order for the newly added element in a Vector

Tags: sorting, vector, java-stream

I have a method, which gets as input a Vector of Employee objects:

```
static void transformData(Vector<Employee> employees){
        employees.stream().sorted((Employee employee1, Employee employee2) -> (employee1.getEmpCode().compareTo(employee2.getEmpCode()) & employee1.getFromDate().compareTo(employee2.getFromDate())) );
    }
```

I call this function with a Vector prepopulated with some objects (that are unordered). It works fine, sorting the stream's underlying Vector.

However, before calling this method, if I add some element in that Vector, the new element gets added in the end & not where I expect it to be, as per alphabetical order for empCode:

```
employees.add(new EmployeeTimeLog("MMX12", fromDate, toDate, 2));
    // New Employee gets added in the end, fine.
    transformData(employees);
    // Now the Vector is sorted, however, the new element is still positioned in the end.
```

Can someone point to me where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.List; 
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Comparator; 
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class TestPgm {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employees.add(new Employee("AA12","A","A"));
    employees.add(new Employee("CC12","C","C"));
    employees.add(new Employee("KK12","K","K"));
    employees.add(new Employee("BB12","B","B"));
    employees = transformData(employees);       
    employees.forEach(e -> System.out.println("Id:"+ e.getEmpCode()));      
    System.out.println("Adding another employee");
    employees.add(new Employee("II12", "I", "I"));
    employees = transformData(employees);
    employees.forEach(e -> System.out.println("Id:"+ e.getEmpCode()));      
 }

 static List<Employee> transformData(List<Employee> employees){

 List employeeList = employees.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getEmpCode)).collect(Collectors.toList());
     return employeeList;
 }
}
```

This will give the output:

```
Id:AA12
Id:BB12
Id:CC12
Id:KK12
Adding another employee
Id:AA12
Id:BB12
Id:CC12
Id:II12
Id:KK12
```

Note, you have the stream the results and collect them into a collection.

Comment: Thanks, Romin, that worked :). Though I found this little strange. It gave me sorted Vector until I changed code to add one more element (before calling transform). Couldn’t find reason why it requires collect() call for that purpose.